# How to store values that are converted to decimal with 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I fetch some data from database. There are float columns in the table I fetched. And i want to show that values of columns in numericUpDown control. Becouse of this i fetch these columns with CAST function;

```
Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
sdaRecete = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Kod, Ad, MalzemeSayisi, Sayilan, Tartilan, CAST(AgirlikNominal as numeric(10, 2)) as 'Nominal Ağırlık', CAST(AgirlikAltDeger as numeric(10, 2)) as 'Ağırlık Alt Limit', CAST(AgirlikUstDeger as numeric(10, 2)) as 'Ağırlık Üst Değer' FROM Recete", connection);
sdaRecete.Fill(dtrecete);
dgvRecipe.DataSource = dtrecete;
```

The problem is that; i want to edit values of numericUpDown controls and than store the values back to the database. To achieve this;

```
private void nudNominalWeight_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvRecipeUpdateSelectedRow(6, nudNominalWeight.Value);
        }

        private void dgvRecipeUpdateSelectedRow(int cellIndex, object value)
        {
            int rowIndex = dgvRecipe.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            object[] items = dtrecete.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray;
            items[cellIndex] = value;
            dtrecete.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray = items;
        }
```

and when i click to save button this;

```
private void tsSaveRecipe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommandBuilder scbRecete = new SqlCommandBuilder(sdaRecete);
            sdaRecete.Update(dtrecete);
        }
```

But code does not work. I cant store the values. How can i store these values? Is the problem about my using CAST function?

Comment: What kind of values do you submit to the sdaRecete object? What is the sql query in the scbRecete object?

Comment: the sql query is  `"SELECT ID, Kod, Ad, MalzemeSayisi, Sayilan, Tartilan, CAST(AgirlikNominal as numeric(10, 2)) as 'Nominal Ağırlık', CAST(AgirlikAltDeger as numeric(10, 2)) as 'Ağırlık Alt Limit', CAST(AgirlikUstDeger as numeric(10, 2)) as 'Ağırlık Üst Değer' FROM Recete"`

Comment: That query will select values, it cannot insert values, where is the insert query, since as you can see from your question, you're trying to insert (store) values, is that correct?

Comment: `SqlCommandBuilder scbRecete = new SqlCommandBuilder(sdaRecete);
            sdaRecete.Update(dtrecete);`
this code updates the dtrecete and save the changes that is made to the database. No need to insert or update command

Comment: Do you get any error?